# Get certain element of remote site with lack of unique criteria

Tags: php, dom

Sorry if this seem unclear will explain it

I am trying to get certain element that may be either `<iframe>` `<script>` from remote page,

this remote page have many `<iframe>` and `<script>` but the one i need have no unique criteria like specific `id` the most unique criteria is the position of it in the code, its always above this piece of code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in other words the `iframe` or `script`  i want is just in the line above the jquery reference

what are the methods i can relies on to get this iframe

Comment: Show me the website and the piece of code you need..

Comment: @nathanhayfield No this is part of application that get this iframe automatically

Comment: @VishnuVishwa check it here http://pastebin.com/DRCrnXS7

Comment: @mirandakerry : and what do you need to grab from that code ?

Comment: DOM is a tree structure. If you can find one node in the tree, you can go up/down/across the branches to find the node you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$file = file('www.yoururl.html');

foreach($file as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($value, 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js')) {
        echo $file[$key-1];
        break;
    };
};
```

you could use regex to make sure you didn't pick up anything else on the line:-

```
    preg_match('/<(iframe|script).+<\/(iframe|script)>/', $file[$key-1], $matches);
    echo $matches[0];
```

Comment: You saved me days of search really thanks for great help. i still need a bit help what if `www.yoururl.html` is not in this way but i formed through certain variables got with $_REQUEST

Comment: You saved me days of search really thanks for great help. i still need a bit help what if `www.yoururl.html` is not in this way but i formed through certain variables got with $_REQUEST check this paste http://pastebin.com/G3hR9iPX i dont know why this code doesnt work

Comment: I can't see how the way the url is formed makes any difference. It's possible to do if it's not on one line also but depends on formatting. Do you have a live example of the source url?

Comment: same example in pastebin but sometimes this method is not returning anything just return empty page i think this due to formating and i dont know when formating wil be ideal for this method to work, so is there is any way that we got the code and reformat it so for every line to have only on element or tag so we can get exact desired line?

Comment: here is example of code that this method doesn't work on http://pastebin.com/BQv8hDDg